# ‘toRow’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘ToRow’

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

I'm learning Haskell so I decided to write a web app. I did choose PostgreSQL Simple to work with the database. I successfully connected to it and tried simple math operations but I'm having problems trying to map records to data. This code doesn't compile:

```
module Handlers.SurveyReplies where

import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

data AnswersSet = AnswersSet {
  sex ∷ Integer,
  ageRange ∷ Integer,
  country ∷ Integer,
  commune ∷ Maybe Integer
} deriving (Show)

instance FromRow AnswersSet where
  fromRow = AnswersSet <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field

instance ToRow AnswersSet where
toRow r = [toField (sex r), toField (ageRange r), toField (country r), toField (commune r)]
```

The error is:

```
    ‘fromRow’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘FromRow’
   |
17 |   fromRow = AnswersSet <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field
   |   ^^^^^^^
```

And also:

```
    ‘toRow’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘ToRow’
   |
20 |         toRow r = [toField (sex r), toField (ageRange r), toField (country r), toField (commune r)]
   |         ^^^^^
```

I looked some sample projects ([this among others](https://github.com/keoko/postgresql-simple-examples/blob/master/Todo.hs#L27)) but I don't get what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Your type is very strange. Why all those `Integer`s? FYI, multiple choice for sex is not likely to work well for mammals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The module `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple` only exports the type classes `ToRow` and `FromRow`, without any of their methods.

For those methods you need to import the modules `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.ToRow` and `Database.PostgreSQL.Simple.FromRow`, as is done in the sample you linked to.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple (ToRow)` was the same. I need to read a little bit more about modules 

Comment: That import only bring the type class into scope(even if the module exported both the class and its methods), and that only exists in the type-level namespace. Haskell has a different namespace for types and values.

Comment: I see! Thank you again!